# GDB on subtle lines when next or step

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, embedded, gdbserver

I use GDB to debug an embedded linux target board. On target board gdbserver is running the stripped binary application. On PC side I run application which has debug symbols attached.

From PC via ethernet connection I do "target remote ip:port" and there is a healthy connection to gdbserver. I add break points in some functions and continue. Debugger successfully break as expected when I trigger external event and program breaks in my simple function. Weird behaviour starts at this point. When I do step or next in GDB console instead of next line it goes to previous line than goes to two lines forward and goes back two lines backward. Each time I do next or step this continues. There is no loops or jumps, code should just go line by line but it doesn't. Why GDB behaves like this? What should I do to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is normal behaviour for code to which a high level of optimisation has been applied.  Unless you are actually intending to debug the optimiser, executing optimised code in a debugger is almost useless.

From the [manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Optimized-Code.html):

> *When you debug a program compiled with ‘-g -O’, remember that the optimizer has rearranged your code; the debugger shows you what is really there. Do not be too surprised when the execution path does not exactly match your source file!*

Comment: "executing optimised code in a debugger is almost useless" -- on the contrary, many bugs *only* show up in optimized builds, and one eventually needs to learn how to debug optimized code. But it's true that *if* the bug shows up in un-optimized code as well, then it's much easier to debug un-optimized variant.

Comment: @EmployedRussian : I did say "*almost*" for exactly that reason - so it is hardly *contrary*. Such bugs normally occur through use of *undefined behaviour*.  If you end up having to debug optimised code for any reason other than a compiler bug, it probably says something about the general quality of the code in the first instance.  Often such bugs can be avoided by setting warning levels high and fixing them all, or using static analysis.  Often bugs such as potentially uninitialised variables can be spotted by the optimiser during compilation due to the data flow analysis that it performs.